# Issue in Date Format in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using below code.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'SuspensionHistoryDate' => 'required|date_format:"mm/dd/YYYY"',
    ];
}
```

below is the value that I tried to post "03/23/2016".

I am getting below mentioned message.

> The d l issue date does not match the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Can you please guide if I am missing anything?

Comment: I'd suggest that the mask has to correspond to the format options for [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or [date_parse_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php), ie `m/d/Y`, rather than an MS Excel style format mask..... exactly as the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-date-format) tell you

Comment: It works when I changed the code to `'SuspensionHistoryDate' => 'required|date'`

Comment: It will work with `'required|date'` because you're not demanding a specific date format, just allowing Laravel to use one that's supported as valid by default

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments you need to be setting the date format as a valid PHP format - which `mm/dd/YYYY` isn't.

You can see more on the available formats that PHP will accept [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), but based off you wanting a month/day/year format then this would work:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'SuspensionHistoryDate' => 'required|date_format:"m/d/Y"',
    ];
}
```

Note that using `d` means that the day needs to be represented as two digits and so may need to have a leading zero. You can use `j` instead to still have a numerical representation without leading zeros.